# How to Insert data through multiple forms to multiple tables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi i am new to laravel i have 3 forms ie customer ,service,contact all have different tables like customer ,service,contact i need to do insert for these in database in laravel.

**Service Form:**

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('service.store') }}">
                          @csrf

                           <div class="input-w">
                              <label class="label-style">Service Type:</label>
                              <span><select class="form-control" required >
                                <option type="brillare">Brillare</option>
                                <option type="hair">Hair</option>
                              </select></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="input-w">
                              <label name="service_name">Service Name:</label>
                              <span><input id="service_name" name="service_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Service Name" required ></span>
                          </div>

                          <div class="input-w">
                              <label name="service_price">Service Price:</label>
                              <span><input type="number" id="service_price" name="service_price" class="form-control" required placeholder="0000.00"></span>
                          </div>                       

                          <div align="center" class="button_style">
                           <p style="margin:15px -40px 20px 182px"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_service" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-success"></p>

                          </div> 


                        </form>
```

**Migration:**

```
Route::get('/service', function () {
    return view('service');
});




<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class ServiceTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('service', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('servicetype');
            $table->string('servicename');
            $table->string('serviceprice');            
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('service');
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        return view("service");
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request, Service $service)
    {
        //

        $service->servicetype = $request->service_type;
        $service->servicename = $request->service_name;
        $service->serviceprice = $request->service_price;

         $service->create();
        return redirect()->route('service.show');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

i need 
service form insert to service table
customer form insert to customer table
contact form insert to contact table
in laravel 5.8

Comment: you can do it in one controller with sql query can you give more information your about your question and show me your all html form customer service and contact

Comment: simillar 2 more forms customer like customer info name moblie email

Comment: your all forms submitted same time? what you want exactly? do you want to insert data from 3 forms with one controller

Comment: if your form different you should create 3 model and 3 controller

Comment: yep all are different i created 3 model 3 controller 3 views .but in service view form after submit button i get this error ReflectionException
Class App\Http\Controllers\Service does not exist

Comment: you wrote ServiceController it is your class name it is not only Service

Comment: can you show me your route file

Comment: both route and controller in top . How should be in Service Contorlller plz i am new to this so lot of confussions

Comment: where you write this route 'service_info' when you submit form it submitted this 'service_info' route and it calling 'Service' controller not ServiceController so it gives to you error just show you should change it to ServiceController from Service, I saw your route and there is onlu one line code

Comment: No service_info i just gave path for testing my form action is  <form method="POST" action="{{ route('service.store') }}">

Comment: replace it to route('ServiceController.store')

Comment: no i get error with it route('ServiceController.store') ,route('service.store') }} is working fine

Comment: can you show me error

Comment: it is showing now  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'service_type' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `services` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2019-09-11 04:29:47, 2019-09-11 04:29:47))

Comment: thanks it is solve table was missing updated_at, created_at fields i added it solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have 3 entities.

1. Customer
2. Service
3. Contact

For all 3 entities you would want to have a model, a controller and a migration. If the entities have relations between one and other you can specify those in the model. Take a look at the link for more information about relationships in laravel.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

When you have made the relations in the model, made the migrations its time to move on to the controller.

In the controller you will have the following functions:

```
public function index(Contact $model)
{
    // return index view
}

public function create()
{
    // return create form view
}

// Option 1
public function store(Request $request, Service $service)
{
    $service->create($request->all);
    return redirect()->route('your.route');
}

// Option 2
public function store(Request $request, Service $service)
{
    $service->servicetype = $request->service_type;
    $service->servicename = $request->service_name;
    $service->serviceprice = $request->service_price;

     $service->create();
    return redirect()->route('your.route');
}


public function edit() 
{
    // return edit view
}

public function update(Request $request,  Service $service)
{
    $service->update($request->all);
    //return view
}

public function destory(Service $service)
{
    $service->delete();
    // return view
}
```

Comment: hi i know the store function but simillar to this i have 2 other forms i am not able to insert those customer form and contact form

Comment: The best practice in this case would be to create 3 models, 3 controllers and 3 migrations. It will keep in clean and will make it easier to find stuff.

Comment: i did the same does it work like that insert is not working what about create.blade.php i am fully confused

Comment: Ill adjust my awnser

Comment: all three are differnt no relationship.. one is service i posted the code another customer

Comment: If there are no relationships you can just repeat the same strucutre. Create 3 models, migrations and controllers. Create the views needed for those controllers and write the functions. If you do that you can do what you want.

Comment: i did create 3 models 3 view files 3 controllers. in service view after cliking submit button i get this error ReflectionException
Class App\Http\Controllers\Service does not exist

Comment: The best practice in creating those files would be to create a Service model and a ServiceController. You can use php artisan commands to make your life easier.

Comment: yep i created though php artisan commands    i get these error ReflectionException
Class App\Http\Controllers\Service does not exist   and also in console i get Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: What is the post action?

Comment: <form method="POST" action="{{ route('service.store') }}">

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/reflectionexception-class-apphttpcontrollersadminadmincontroller-does-not-exist